# Shall I use @DatabaseView in Room with LiveData?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-livedata, database-view

Its working if run query through main thread.
If I try to get DatabaseView with Livedata POJO, Its throwing error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add the same observer with different lifecycles
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observe(LiveData.java:197)
    at MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.kt:45)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7058)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

DatabaseView class

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT ss_pack.id as id, ss_pack.title as title, ss_pack.primary_value as primaryValue FROM ss_pack JOIN favourite WHERE favourite.ss_pack_id = ss_pack.id")
data class AllFavourites(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val primaryValue: String
)
```

My Dao

```
interface FavouriteDao {
@Query("SELECT * from AllFavourites")
fun getFavorites(): LiveData<List<AllFavourites>>

@Insert
fun insertFav(favourite: Favourite)
}
```

My Repository

```
class MyRepository(val favoriteDao: FavoriteDao, val categoryDao: CategoryDao) {

val favourites: LiveData<List<AllFavourites>> = favoriteDao.getFavorites()
val categories: LiveData<List<Category>> = categoryDao.loadAllCategories()
}
```

ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){
private val myRepository: MyRepository
val favourites: LiveData<List<AllFavourites>>

init {
    val favoriteDao = SDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).favoriteDao()
    myRepository = myRepository(favoriteDao, categoryDao)
    favourites = passwordRepository.favourites
}
}
```

Error throwing when I call this observe in my fragment

```
viewModel.favourites.observe(this, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { favorites ->
        favorites?.let {
            print("FAVORITE SIZE ${favorites.size}")
        }
    })
```

Tell me how to use DatabaseView with LiveData or kotlin coroutines with this MVVM Pattern.

I need to print that FAVORITE SIZE from my fragment through background thread not from UI thread.

Comment: have you create new viewmodel for your fragment?.or you are using shared view model by all the other fragment.

Comment: @DeepNaik new viewmodel for my fragment, not shared one.

Comment: And are you observing FAVORITE in both your fragments?.if yes that won't possible.

Comment: No I am using only one fragment which is observing AllFavourite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateView()` can be called multiple times for the same Fragment instance (as the view is destroyed when the Fragment is put on the back stack, but the Fragment instance itself is kept around).

You should **always** use [`viewLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#getViewLifecycleOwner()) rather than `this` when using `observe()` in `onCreateView()` as this ensures that the previous observer (tied to the last time `onCreateView()` was called) is properly cleaned up:

```
viewModel.favourites.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer { favorites ->
    favorites?.let {
        print("FAVORITE SIZE ${favorites.size}")
    }
})
```

Comment: Yes I had used my fragment in 2 places. both initialised at same time so it throws an error. thanks

Comment: I usually `observe()` in `onViewCreated()`, not `onCreateView()`. Just to confirm: we should be using `viewLifecycleOwner` in that circumstance as well, correct?

Comment: @CommonsWare - both are fine, as long as you are using `viewLifecycleOwner`, yep!